# facebook app to pull posts in website not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pull posts from facebook to my website. I created a facebook app for the same(https://www.facebook.com/kcm.edu.np/).
Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var accessToken ='975498622499311|eKS53jkWW4F74JEShrDHuJNwOwg';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/kcm.edu.np/posts?fields=full_picture,id,is_published,link,story,message,name,updated_time,description,from,source,caption,created_time,permalink_url,type,target&access_token=' + accessToken + '&limit=6',
        type: 'GET',

        success:function(result){
            $("#hidden-next-feed").val(result.paging.next);
            $.each( result.data, function( index, value ) {
                var link;
                var imgSrc = '';
                var name = '';
                var message = '';
                if(typeof(value.link) != "undefined" && value.link !== null) {
                    link = value.link;
                } else {
                    link = value.permalink_url;
                }
                if(typeof(value.full_picture) != "undefined" && value.full_picture !== null) {
                    imgSrc = value.full_picture;
                }
                if(typeof(value.name) != "undefined" && value.name !== null) {
                    name = value.name;
                }
                if(typeof(value.message) != "undefined" && value.message !== null) {
                    message = value.message;
                }
                $("#facebook-feed").append(
                    '<div class="grid-item"><a href="'+value.permalink_url+'" target="_blank">'+
                    '<div class="thumbnail">'+
                    '<img src="'+imgSrc+'" alt="'+name+'" >'+
                    '<div class="caption">'+
                    '<h3>'+name+'</h3>'+
                    '<p>'+message+'</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</a></div>'
                );
            });
            $container.masonry('destroy');
            $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $container.masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                    percentPosition: true
                });
            });
        },
        error:function() {
            $("#facebook-feed").html('Failed To Load Resource');
        }
    });
});
```

Problem:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'kcm.edu.np' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "FsBLqadb5Oz"
   }
}
```

How am I to solve this ? Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to Facebook now and reset your app secret. The app secret you should treat as a password and don't show anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting of the page visibility needs to be set to "Visible to everyone". This option can be found under - Setting > General > Country Restrictions.

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should **NEVER** reveal the `App Secret` on client-side, use PHP sdk instead and make ajax requests to the server. As @WizKid
   said,

> *Application Secret Key should always be treated as your password*

-- failing to do
    that might get your account and app compromised. Reset it ASAP.

2. The correct way to retrieve a page posts is by accessing the feed endpoint:

   `/<id>/feed?fields=<fields>`

In your case the id of the page is: 1451944358387272